# is_a? and dRuby objects

Tags: ruby, drb, druby

I'm working with dRuby and basicly I'm calling a remote method that returns me an object.

In the clientside I have this code:

```
handle_error(response) if response.is_a?(Error)
```

where response is the DRbObject. (I've developed this code before using dRuby and I'm returning an Error object if something went wrong). The problem is that now

```
response.is_a?(Error)
```

comes back with "false" because the object is actually a DRbObject. 
Any idea on how I can check the class of my application object?

Thanks!
Roberto

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm not sure how DRb manages the remote objects, I'd expect it to modify #kind_of?   to keep the class hierarchy on the remote object, so you could do:

```
response.kind_of?(Error)
```

If this doesn't work you can always ask it if it responds to an specific method and go from there

```
response.respond_to?(some_method_on_your_errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not work around the problem by using [Duck Typing](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/78502)? Instead of checking for whether the object is an Error, check whether the object responds to a call to get the error information. If it does, handle the error according to that information, otherwise handle the (non-error) response.